# Simple tool for cropping and scaling images

Tags: tools, crop, zoom

I am wondering if there is a **simple** and **quick** tool for cropping and scaling images.

For example, if when creating a web page for an online store, you might need a set of images for each product. Lets say you need half a dozen images each of a certain size. Is there a tool that would allow you to quickly create such a set of images (ie, you drag in each image, pan and zoom, then export). Ideally, you would be able to define the image set, by specifying the dimensions of each image as a template that could be used again.

Comment: You should look into Imagemagick or Photoshop's batch editing.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for the comment. Photoshop is more complicated that what I am hoping for as is ImageMagick.

Comment: We have a large amount of questions on the topic.  If you have trouble with them you can edit to post your code and we can help.

Comment: Hi @Matt. Thanks for the offer and advice, but there is no problem - they just take longer than a simple app built for that single purpose would. I just want to know if such an app exists (if it does not, I intend to make it)

Comment: I feel like this is one of those questions where the OP would have found what he was looking for, if he or she had googled for 5 minutes. --- Either way, maybe you could try the batch processing in [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/). There are stand-alone applications, but many photo manager applications have batch processing.

Comment: What is wrong with leaving the scaling and sizing to the web application? Most frameworks and content management systems are perfectly capable of executing such trivial tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to edit this post and add the tool you use plus any resources you feel are useful.

### [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

The common way of doing mass cropping in a webdev environment is to use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) Its a command line tool that has bindings to nearly anything (like PHP) and its free  and can easily be built into your web app frontend. So your web application would handle the cropping for you.

If you don't want to use command line there's a nice web frontend for Imagemagic called [Converseen](http://converseen.fasterland.net/), that makes it easy to use without needing to delve into the *cmd*.

Imagemagick is a incredibly simple tool with many uses.

### [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com)

[irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com) as mentioned by **@Joonas** a pretty comprehensive viewer application and it has a batch tool set that could easily do this conversion. Its a good all around program to have in case you need to do a lot of image batching.

- [Tutorial on batch cropping with Irfanview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_eEKD8AJz0)

### Other Tools

[Here](http://www.hlrnet.com/mbvfree.htm) is a pretty comprehensive list of tools that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this question, we ended up rolling our own Mac app to do what I wanted. Since then, I have found one application that came close to what I was after; [Sketch3](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/). The best thing for me in this app is the export; it is really good at exporting (with @2x, @3x automatically included). However, it falls down at the setup which is too much work for what I was wanting. The app we made does what I wanted better. Unfortunately, I am not in a position to make this tool available.